# database to Highchart ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I want to input JSON data that I have from Database to highchart. but the chart didn't show up but JSON data does. 
In ajax I already separate the category and data, but it's not working. especially because i don't know how to debug this javascript code. when I open inspect the sources in browser but it show nothing. I hope someone can help me

my ViewModel

```
public class DataByYear
{
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public string year { get; set; }
}
```

this is my Provider

```
public List<DataByYear> GetDataByYear()
    {
        tesdbEntities entities = new tesdbEntities();
        var data = entities.Database.SqlQuery<DataByYear>("exec DataByYear");
        return data.ToList();
    }
```

I use SP to get the data from database

My Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
        var penjualan = new PenjualanProvider();
        var index = new List<DataByYear>();
        index = penjualan.GetDataByYear();
        return this.Json(index, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and this is my JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Index")',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        success: function (dataChart) {

            var Xaxis = [];
            var dataseries = [];
            for (i = 0; i < DataByYear.length; i++) {
                var items = DataByYear[i];
                var XcategoreisItem = items.year;
                var seriesData = items.Total;

                Xaxis.push(XcategoreisItem);
                dataseries.push(seriesData);
                getchart(Xaxis, dataseries);
            }
        }
    })

});

function getchart(Xaxis, dataseries) {
    $('#data').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line',
            zoomType: 'xy',
            panning: true,
            panKey: 'shift'
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Profit From 2018'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{y}%', 

                }
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: Xaxis
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Y axis text'
            },

            series: dataseries
        }
    });
};
```

---

Comment: In your JavaScript you are receiving JSON which you have named as dataChart, but then you don't reference this and try to reference DataByYear, which will not be defined. You should check the console window for errors or check out one of the many [tutorials](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/) that can teach you how to debug JavaScript in the browser.

Comment: You've used `highcharts` tag, however, your issue is not related to highcharts library. As @JohnM have mentioned you haven't used JSON data that has been received from the backend.